# Oracle select statement where date is greater than 30 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get an ORACLE statement which returns rows that are older than 30 days from the the date of creation.

My table has a field "date_entered" that contains the date and the time it was inserted in the database .

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't asked a question. If you only want particular rows from a table, use a `WHERE` clause. Is this what you wanted to know? Please be more precise as to what you have problems with, when asking questions here.

Comment: Haha, no reason to get huffish :-) You are new and I was pointing out that you haven't asked a proper question. As is, saying that you could use a `WHERE` clause would be a legitimate answer. Your request doesn't make it clear what your actual problem was. Did you want to know how to limit rows in a query? Did you want to know how to express "older" with dates? Did you want to know how to get today's date? Did you want to know how to subtract days from a date? Not making a proper request can keep people from answering, which you want to avoid of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your select statement
WHERE date_entered < TRUNC(SYSDATE)-30